# How would one go about drawing the contour lines for this map in order to draw the cross section?

Tags: geology, rocks, mapping

Good Day. We Received this map as practice for our Geology university module and I have no idea how to draw the strike lines where the different heights intersect the different rock types in order to draw the cross section as there are many different directions for the lines. Can anyone possibly assist in this regard?[image: The Map we received in here as a picture]

Comment: First you need to draw the topographic profile as explained in this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rJru71-b61Y